# e2e Testing in protractor. SignIn

Tags: protractor

I am not able to redirect on required page on sigIn page. It clicks on button but not giving the output as required. Not able to hit the server for further process after signin process.Plz help

```
describe("it should be able to run on different events as defined", function(){
    it("should be get on browser", function(){
        browser.get("http://www.localhost:8100/#/signin");
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://www.localhost:8100/#/signin");
        browser.sleep(2000);
        element(by.css("[ng-model='user.email']")).sendKeys('ash.mat23.23@gmail.com');
        element(by.css("[ng-model='user.email']")).getAttribute('placeholder').then(function(element){
            expect(element).toEqual('Email');
            browser.sleep(2000); 
        });
        element(by.css("[ng-model='user.password']")).sendKeys('123456');
        element(by.css("[ng-model='user.password']")).getAttribute('placeholder').then(function(element){
            expect(element).toEqual('Password (at least 6 characters)');
            browser.sleep(2000);
        });
        element(by.id('signin_submit_btn'));
        browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks...I found the solution..!!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's clicking the button properly? To my mind the line that reads:

```
element(by.id('signin_submit_btn'));
```

Should have a click event on the end, i.e. it should read:

```
element(by.id('signin_submit_btn')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking. It looks to me that you are preforming all actions at the same time. You should make sure filling in the username and password is done before clicking on submit or pressing enter. I hope this helps:

```
describe("it should be able to run on different events as defined", function () {
        it("should be get on browser", function () {
            browser.get("http://www.localhost:8100/#/signin").then(() => {
                expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://www.localhost:8100/#/signin");
                Promise.all([
                    $("[ng-model='user.email']").sendKeys('ash.mat23.23@gmail.com'),
                    $("[ng-model='user.password']").sendKeys('123456'),
                    $("[ng-model='user.email']").getAttribute('placeholder').then(function (element) {
                        expect(element).toEqual('Email');
                    }),
                    $("[ng-model='user.password']").getAttribute('placeholder').then(function (element) {
                        expect(element).toEqual('Password (at least 6 characters)');
                    })
                ]).then(()=>{
                    $('#signin_submit_btn').click(); // or browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
                })
            })
        });
    });
```